# Selected option is not visible in spinner

Tags: java, android

I have used a spinner with dynamic data retrieval from sqllite database, I am able to populate the values not when I select something from it its not showing that.

This is my code:

```
final Spinner defects = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.defects); 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
defects.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Comment: could u show me your logcat ?

Comment: im able to populate data via spinner but when I select some value its not showing 01-02 00:25:26.910: E/SQLiteLog(1276): (1) table DefectTablemain already exists

01-02 00:25:27.900: I/Choreographer(1276): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-02 00:25:32.680: I/Choreographer(1276): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-02 00:25:33.020: I/Choreographer(1276): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: Your error shows that you are doing the time consuming work on the UI thread. Show some more code.

Comment: final Spinner defects = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.defects); 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    defects.setAdapter(adapter1);

Comment: try {
  db = openOrCreateDatabase("Defects.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
  String CREATE_DEFECTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE DefectTablemain ( "
    + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "desc TEXT, "
    + "status TEXT ,"+"user TEXT)";
  db.execSQL(CREATE_DEFECTS_TABLE);
  
 } catch (SQLException e) {
  //UpdateId(defects);
 }

Comment: @Muthu Please post your code in your question only.

Comment: @Muthu: Please edit your question to add the code according to the comments. Do not post your code in comments here.

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch data from the cursor and do the following:

```
defects.setSelection(//position of the selected string);
```

Call this function in your `onCreate()` so that when ever the activity loads, if there is an entry in the database, you could load the following value into the spinner. In case of spinner's all of the data have a position. So in your case you could do the following:

Get the string from your database, and use the following function:

```
public int getpositionof_spinner(String name){
    int index = 0;
    String[] statuslist = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yourspinnerarray);
    for (String string : statuslist) {

        if(string.equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            return index;
        }
        index++;    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, finally you would end up with :

```
defects.setSelection(getpositionof_spinner("value"));
```

You could create a `populate()` function where you can prepopulate the things that are in the database and call them on the `onCreate()` of your app for ease of implementation.

For query you could do the following:

```
public Cursor getContacts(String spinner) {

    String where = KEY_SPINNER + " = '" + spinner + "'";
    Cursor c = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, ALL_KEYS_TO_DATABASE, where, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But where do i need to insert this code "defects.setSelection(//position of the selected string);" what which position should i give here.?

Answer (score 0):

You could use AsyncTask class for fetching data from Database. In doInBackground(...) fetch data and set data on onPostExecute().